# How to perform update function in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have updateFruit function. Where user can update their fruit choice. I get the fruit details from the API. Just to show the concept I displayed the `fruit_temp` like this. All the values inside the `fruit_temp` are fetched through the API which means that the fruit already existed. And now I want to perform update function.

In this update function, user can add new fruit or remove their selected fruit from the option. If new fruit `Mango` is added into the `updateFruit_temp`, it will send data like this

```
 {
    "fruit_db_id": null,
    "fruit_id": 4,
    "status": true,
  }
```

and if user wants to remove example `Papaya` from the fruit selection, it will send data like this

```
 {
    "fruit_db_id": 71,
    "fruit_id": 1,
    "status": false,
  }
```

But now I have problem in updating the fruit, and sending the data into the expected output above. How do I push the new updated value inside the `updateFruit_temp` with the format requested inside the API ? I have to send data to the API like this.

```
//if new fruit is inserted
{
    "fruit_db_id": null,
    "fruit_id": 4,
    "status": true,
  },

//if fruit is removed
{
    "fruit_db_id": 71,
    "fruit_id": 1,
    "status": false,
  }

//if user wants to keep the fruit 

{
    "fruit_db_id": 71,
    "fruit_id": 1,
    "status": true,
  }
```

Below is what I have tried but the `updateFruit_temp` did not respond to a new value of `newFruit` how do I fix this ?

```js
let fruit_temp = [];
let updateFruit_temp = [];
let status = true;

$(document).ready(function() {
  getFruitDetails();
  //updateFruit();


});
const getFruitDetails = () => {
  //getDetail through API and pass the selected value into the fruit temp
  fruit_temp = [{
    db_id: 71,
    id: 1,
    name: 'papaya'
  }, {
    db_id: 73,
    id: 3,
    name: 'apple'
  }];

  //console.log(fruit_temp);

}


const updateFruit = () => {

  let newFruit = $('#updateFruit').val();
  fruit_temp = fruit_temp.filter(function(el) {
    if (el != null) {
      updateFruit_temp.push({
        "fruit_db_id": (el.db_id == undefined) ? null : el.db_id,
        "fruit_id": (el.id == undefined) ? newFruit : el.id,
        "status": (el.db_id == undefined || el.db_id == null) ? false : true,
      }) - 1;
      return el;
    }
  });

  console.log(newFruit);

  console.log(updateFruit_temp);


}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<label> Add new fruit :</label>
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" id="updateFruit">
  <option value="1" selected>Papaya</option>
  <option value="2">Honeydew</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Apple</option>
  <option value="4">Mango</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" onclick="updateFruit()"> Update Fruit Choice</button>
```

It's not error, it just did not perform the update function. Meaning that my `updateFruit_temp` is not working.

This is what I'm trying to achieve in the `updateFruit_temp` if user select fruit `honeydew, apple and removed papaya` from the selection.

```
{
    "fruit_db_id": null,
    "fruit_id": 4,
    "status": true, // add honeydew
  },
{
    "fruit_db_id": 73,
    "fruit_id": 3,
    "status": true, //maintain apple 
  },

{
    "fruit_db_id": 71,
    "fruit_id": 1,
    "status": false,  //remove papaya
  }
```

Comment: _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: Why `.filter()` (`fruit_temp.filter(...)`)?

Comment: @Andreas it is wrong? I usually used this. is that why I'm not getting the output ?

Comment: @Andreas I have update the expected output that I'm trying to achieve. It's not an error,  it just that my method is not working to achieve the expected output

Comment: There appears to be no logical relationship between Fruit and the organization in the list. How should the script know that if the User selects Papaya, should it go to 3rd object?

Comment: @Twisty to correct this method how do I linked it ? any suggestion will do

Comment: @duatree there is no way for me to be able to make any suggestions based on the example you have provided. You need to provide a more complete example so that others can understand the relationship and then they can make suggestions. Perhaps provide a sample of the DB data. Then break it down into small simp0le steps, get, set, update...